# Any real algebraic variety is diffeomorphic to a real algebraic variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, differential-topology, real-algebraic-geometry

Given a smooth proper real algebraic variety can you find a smooth proper real algebraic variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ that is diffeomorphic to it?

Comment: Probably the fake projective planes, which have no deformations and are not even defined over $\mathbb R$, provide counterexamples.

Comment: Do you mean defined over $\bar{{\mathbb Q}}$ rather than ${\mathbb Q}$?

Comment: I believe that Will's comment settles your question. As Moishe implicitly suggests, your question has a positive answer if you replace $\mathbb{Q}$ by $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$.

Comment: Wait, if it's not defined over $\bf R$ how can it be a "real algebraic variety"?

Comment: That's not the issue at all, the problem is that "approximating the defining equations" is not at all useful for this question.

Comment: @vrz The issue is that perturbing the equations a small amount may lead to a much smaller-dimensional variety if the original equations have some redundancy, but that equations with redundancy are necessary (not everything is a complete intersection). There is no way the proof can be made to work.

Comment: That said I don't have another counterexample.

Comment: I had a related question here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/347739/field-of-definition-for-general-type-surfaces and I still don't understand why the answer should be positive when R is replaced by C and Q by \bar{Q} as Chris states above.

Comment: What's the definition of "real algebraic variety" you're using? For example, on the real line $X$, is $1/(1+x^2)$ an element of $\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ or not?

Comment: @JonnyEvans: say your smooth projective variety $X$ is given as the zero locus of $(F_1,\ldots, F_k)$ in $\mathbf{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^n$. Consider the coefficients of the $F_i$'s as indeterminates: this cuts a variety in some $\mathbf{A}^h\times\mathbf{P}^n$ and your original variety is the fiber over a point $p$ in $\mathbf{A}^h$ under projection to the first factor. Since $X$ is smooth, by openness of smoothness, the map is a topological fiber bundle over a neighborhood of $p$, which certainly contains a $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$-point.

Comment: @Qfwfq I use the definition that it's a smooth proper scheme over $\mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{R}$. So the global sections of the affine line are polynomials.

Comment: @Chris: Your argument is not quite correct: the smoothness of a fibre does not imply that the morphism is smooth along the fibre. Of course, the statement is indeed true.

Comment: @ulrich Thanks for pointing out the innacuracy. One can check the smoothness of the projection by applying the Jacobian criterion (correct me if I'm wrong)

Comment: @Chris But you can't necessarily perturb the coefficients of the F_i and stay in the same moduli space (it's not a complete intersection). What if you have a rigid variety defined over C: why should I be able to perturb the equations at all? (e.g. what if your number h equals zero?). This is, however, a discussion of a slightly different question, so perhaps it would be better to move the discussion to that question if you're interested.

Comment: @JonnyEvans: if I have a rigid variety then all the fibers close to $p$ are not only diffeomorphic but also biholomorphic (which implies that rigid varieties have models over $\bar{\mathbb{Q}}$). If my number $h$ is zero it means that the $F_i$'s are zero.

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I misunderstood your comment, but am still confused. Imagine we're talking about twisted cubics (not complete intersections). Then generic points in A^h have empty preimage under this projection. How do you guarantee that the locus of points whose preimage is an honest deformation of X contains a \bar{Q}-point? What stops this locus being something like a line with slope pi? There seems to be something missing from the argument.

Comment: Perhaps you could fix it as follows? If you're working over a transcendental extension of Q like Q(pi) then you could basechange over the map Q(pi) --> Q(t) sending pi to another transcendental number t and get a diffeomorphic variety because the rings are basically the same (unlike if t is algebraic). Now do this for every transcendental t and you get a bunch of points in A^h which have limit points that are not transcendental because C\setminus\bar{Q} is dense in C, and at least one of these must correspond to a nonsingular variety because nonsingularity is a closed condition.

Comment: @JonnyEvans I'm starting to see your point about complete intersections and that my argument is definitely wrong: perturbing slightly the $F_i$'s is going to make the $dF_i$'s "as independent as possible" so it might cut down the dimension

Comment: @JonnyEvans: the issue is settled in https://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/PUTangSp.pdf  section 4.2. So there is a particular subvariety of the above $\mathbf{A}^h$, defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, such that varying the coefficients inside this subvariety defines honest deformations

Comment: Awesome, thanks @Chris!

Answer (score 9):

Edoardo Ballico and Alberto Tognoli proved in their paper *"Algebraic models defined over $\mathbb{Q}$ of differential manifolds"* (Geom. dedicata 42, 155-161, 1992) that every compact differential manifold is diffeomorphic to the real points of a regular affine variety defined over $\mathbb{Q}$.

For non-smooth algebraic varieties there are obstructions to descend from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{Q}$, there is a recent paper by Adam Parusinski and Guillaume Rond "*Algebraic varieties are homeomorphic to varieties defined over number fields"* [arXiv 1810.00808](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.00808) on this subject.

Edit : let me recall some basic facts about real algebraic sets (I refer to *"Real algebraic geometry"* Bochnak, Coste and Roy).

1. A complete nonsingular affine real algebraic variety is projective (see BCR 3.4 p.74-75)
2. An algebraic subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is complete if and only if it is closed and bounded (3.4.9 and 3.4.10).

Comment: but we want a proper variety not affine one

Comment: As in the comment I just wrote to the OP, here by "real algebraic variety" is it meant something for which $1/(1+x^2)$ is a globally defined regular function on the real line or not?

Comment: @Qfwfq I expect not (or it would be a quite exotic notion of "regular function")

Comment: @YCor: I agree it'd be exotic, but see Example1.5 here [ http://web.math.unifi.it/gruppi/algebraic-geometry/RealAG_basic.pdf ] - if that injection of real points (which I think is regarded there as a "map of real varieties") came from a map of schemes, it would imply that $x/(1+x^2)$ was a regular function on the real line (consider the case $n=1$, take a component of that map and read it in the affine chart $x_1\neq 0$ of $\mathbb{P}^1$, and let $x=x_0/x_1$ be the homogeneous coordinate for that chart). Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Qfwfq I don't think the authors uses the word "regular". I don't know if there's a standard name for a rational map that is regular on the set of real points.

Comment: @YCor: right, maybe they don't call it "regular". But it seems to me they're considering a different category (i.e. more maps/morphisms are allowed) than the full subcategory of schemes over $\mathbb{R}$ that are, say, finite type reduced etc. And they call these things "real algebraic varieties". That may be standard in real AG?

Comment: @Qfxfq I am not an expert in real algebraic geometry, but it seems quite standard to use fo "regular functions" rational functions $f/g$ such that $g$ does not vanish on the real locus. You can have a look at Bochnak, Coste, Roy (cited above, in particular definition 3.2.1) or also at "Topology of real algebraic sets" by Akbulut and King.

Comment: but then this answer is using a different definition of real variety (under the definition meant in question an affine variety that is projective is zero-dimensional).